# How to Save EndNote Output Style in my computer?

Tags: endnotes

I have editted an output style in EndNote

I changed Biblography Template and would like to send the new style with changes to my colleague.

How can I save the new style in my computer as a file?

I tried File > Save As

But I got a small box suggesting a new name to be saved on the existing EndNote

[image]

How to save that as a File ?

Comment: I'm sorry but EndNote questions are really off topic here.  I think you can find the answer here: https://community.endnote.com/t5/EndNote-Styles-Filters-and/Export-Customized-Output-Style/td-p/57572

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about EndNote are off topic.